# How to obtain the variance of my dependent variable in a linear regression with R?

Tags: r, regression, variance, linear-model

How can I obtained the estimated variance of a linear model when using R, i.e.

\begin{equation}
\widehat{var(y)}.
\end{equation}

Comment: `var(fitted(lm_model))` do you need this one?

Comment: @Dmitrij Post an answer!

Comment: What does this expression $\widehat{var(y)}$ mean?  Suppose the data are $(x_i,y_i)$ and the $y_i$ are random variables with expectations $\beta x_i$ for some unknown coefficient(s) $\beta$.  Do you want the variance of the set of $\beta x_i$ (either assuming the $x_i$ are fixed or under some distributional assumptions for them) or do you want to estimate the variance of the $y_i$?  The latter is larger than the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Dimitrij's comment is right on, and I didn't previously know about the fitted function,

Still, I think that it is helpful to know that the model output includes the fitted values. The content of the model output can be determined using `attributes(xymodel)`, and this will show that `xymodel` has an item `fitted.model` that can be accessed using `xymodel$fitted.values`. Then, it is straightforward to calculate the variance of this vector using the `var` function:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- 1:10  
y <- 2 * (x + runif(10))
xymodel <- lm(y~x)
print(xymodel$fitted.values)
ans <- var(xymodel$fitted.values)
print(ans) # answer to O.P.

# same as Dimitrij's answer
ans == var(fitted(xymodel))
```